# Laravel Cron Using For Loop

Tags: laravel, foreach, cron

I am using Laravel cron that runs after each 1 minute. I am using loop in the file to send messages to each user. Some time it sends multiple messages to the user. I want to know what is the best way to use for loop with Laravel cron. I am using laravel/framework": "5.5.*

I am already using withoutOverlapping() method. But sometimes it sends duplicate messages to the same user not every user. May be loop runs twice. I am using recurring timing, means once one task is complete it will automatically scheduled for the next day according to each user. This is what the loop checks and works accordingly. After each one minute loop will repeat same task for the users.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/scheduling#preventing-task-overlaps, but this would only apply if your command took more than a minute to iterate all the Users.

Comment: I am already using withoutOverlapping() method. But sometimes it sends duplicate messages to the same user not every user.

Comment: Please try to include that information in your question, so we don't suggest things you've already tried  Anyway, if that's what's happening, it's probably an issue with your code implementation, which you didn't include in your question, so it'll be pretty hard to help you unless you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77565519/edit) and include more information.

Comment: Okay I will check my script. So this is confirmed that using withoutOverlapping cron will wait for the previous task and after complete it will run for the next task ?

Comment: Any intention to upgrade your Laravel5.5?

Comment: Not now. For now I just want to resolve this issue.

Comment: `->withoutOverlapping()` will not start a new instance of the same command if one is already running; it doesn't matter if it completes (successfully or otherwise), it simply will not have the same command running twice (at least that's how I understand it/how it's worked in my experience). Essentially, the command is skipped.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: $schedule->command('SendTemplates:cron')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping(10);
This is how I was using command in kernal.php.
Now I have removed "10" from the brackets and simply use command as following:-
$schedule->command('SendTemplates:cron')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();

Answer (score 0):

Its is more likely you may have run your script a few times and they are still running in the background which is why you are getting duplicate emails.

Try to restart your server and mysql then this will stop all previous processes from processing.

For the code to handle large loops its best to use the laravel chunk function like this

```
$data = User::select('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'age')
->where('age', '>', '10')
->chunk(50, function($results) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        // send email here
    }
});
```